# How to make the function known by the command.js and index.d.ts?

Tags: reactjs, cypress, autotest

I got this test in Cypress, the problem is that it won't pass any values to the cypress.commands.add

Commands.js:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomer', (customer) => {
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('input[name="id"]').clear()
    cy.get('input[name="id"]').type(customer.cust_id)
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('input[name="name"]').clear().type(customer.name);
})
```

Index.d.ts:

```
declare namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
        createCustomer(
            cust_id: string,
            name: string): Chainable<string>
    }
}
```

Test.spec.ts

```
describe('Create customer 1st', () => {
    it('first condition for customer', () => {
        cy.createCustomer('A0001', 'Chappy Rose') 
    })
})
```

It seems that test.spec.ts does not pass the values to the commands.js.

Please help. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing two parameters in your test *customer id* and *customer name*, so your custom command should be like this :

```
Cypress.Commands.add('createCustomer', (id, name) => {
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('input[name="id"]').clear()
    cy.get('input[name="id"]').type(id)
    cy.wait(1000)
    cy.get('input[name="name"]').clear().type(name);
})
```